# XMLHttpRequest cannot load? I am using already webserver

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors, restangular

I am fetching a resource from wordnik api in my angular app using Restangular, I have searched this site for other answers to this problem, mainly the focus of the answers were on using a webserver instead of directly accessing the resource in browser but i am already using a server, using jetbeans IDE's built-in server, i also tried localhost on node then using gulp too, but the error still persist, here is my complete error to give you a better idea

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/dog/definations?api_key=a2a73e7b926c…f50eb4ae5&includeRelated=true&includeTags=false&limit=5&useCanonical=false. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

and here is my restangular code fetching the resource

```
var params = {
  limit: "5",
  includeRelated: "true",
  useCanonical:"false",
  includeTags:"false",
  api_key:apiKey
};
var encodedRecword = encodeURI(recword);
var service = WordnikRestangular.all(encodedRecword).all('definations');
service.get("", params).then(function(data) {

   //play with data

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CORS issue ([Mozilla CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)), however i see two other potential problems:

1. `var service = WordnikRestangular.all(encodedRecword).all('definitions');` - it has to be "defin**i**tions" and not "defin**a**tions"
2. Skip the `Port 80` on the URL - it's port 80 by default
3. Try using https

If that doesn't work try Angulars `$http.jsonp` to directly access the API (JSONp should be possible without CORS issues). If the problem persists, let me know.

Comment: thanks ...you are spot on.. my bad... sometimes you just get caught at wrong places that you cant see the simple solution that is right in front of you all along